# Css class not changing the border colour of the textbox

Tags: css, stylesheet

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 and FluentValidation for validating my view models.

I currently have my text boxes styled like this:

```
input[type="text"]{border:1px solid #c9d7e1;padding-left:2px;}
```

and I have a validator css class for if there is an error with the input:

```
.input-validation-error{border:1px solid #ff0000;background-color:#ffeeee;}
```

When validation kicks in then the background colour of the textbox is #ffeeee which is correct, but it does not make the border of the textbox red (#ff0000).  It is still #c9d7e1.  How do I change my styles so that it makes the border of the textbox red?

I also have my textareas defined as:

```
textarea{border:1px solid #c9d7e1;padding-left:2px;}
```

and the border gets set to red.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `input[type="text"]` is [more specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than `.input-validation-error` so it takes priority.

```
input[type="text"].input-validation-error{
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color:#ffeeee;
}
```

will do the job.

Comment: @David: If it takes preference then why did it change the background colour to #ffeeee?  Is it because no colour was specified in input[type="text"]?

Comment: I also have a textarea defined in my style with exactly the same properties as the textbox and it's border colour gets set to red.  This is my css class: textarea{border:1px solid #c9d7e1;padding-left:2px;}

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS class. That is a CSS rule-set. It doesn't even have a class selector.

Comment: Why is it setting the border of the textarea to red and not the textbox.  Not making sense.

Comment: Because `textarea` is less specific than `.input-validation-error` which is less specific than `input[type="text"]`

Comment: It works. Is there a shorter way of doing this: input[type="text"].input-validation-error{border:1px solid #f00;background-color:#fee;}
textarea.input-validation-error{border:1px solid #f00;background-color:#fee;}

Comment: Thanks. Obvious in hindsight, but the default MS supplied MVC3 style sheet has this bug in as shipped and I couldn't work out why it wasn't working. The default style sheet is pretty awful as it hits everything at global levels.